# regex and string

Tags: c#, regex, string, match

Consider the following:

```
string keywords = "(load|save|close)";
Regex x = new Regex(@"\b"+keywords+"\b");
```

I get no matches. However, if I do this:

```
Regex x = new Regex(@"\b(load|save|close)\b");
```

I get matches. How come the former doesn't work, and how can I fix this? Basically, I want the keywords to be configurable so I placed them in a string.

Comment: I see. I missed out something very obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing another verbatim string specifier (`@` prefixed to the last `\b`):

```
Regex x = new Regex(@"\b" + keywords + @"\b");
```

Answer (score 8):

The last `\b` in the first code snippet needs a verbatim string specifier (`@`) in front of it as well as it is a seperate string instance.

```
string keywords = "(load|save|close)"; 
Regex x = new Regex(@"\b"+keywords+@"\b");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex x = new Regex(@"\b"+keywords+@"\b");
```

You forgot additional `@` before second `"\b"`